# Extracting field values to Excel by iterating in ArcGIS ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, iteration

I have a database with a lot of feature classes containing shapefiles. 
What I want to do is to use ModelBuilder in order to iterate through all the feature classes and for each feature class go through the point shapefiles to extract a field value. The field value is then to be exported to an Excel file.

[image: Workflow in model builder]

You can see my workflow in ModelBuilder in the attached image.
An Excel file is created but it doesn't contain any data at all, only the column headers.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Don't know why it is empty, but I can say your model is horribly inefficient, you have made the classic mistake of connecting everything in one model. You need to Collect your datasets into a list in a SUB-MODEL then merge and process in a master model. Have a look at this [Q&A](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/123306/iterate-with-sub-model-iteration) see how they are collecting in a sub-model. See that it is a model within a model.